# How to execute a specific method from my java program on cmd?

Tags: java, cmd

I have a java program define like this :

```
public class MyClass{    
   public String getPathBetween(String path,String folderName,String extension){..}
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{...}
}
```

After compiling the program using following command :

```
$ javac MyClass.java
```

I can run the main method like this :

$ java MyClass

But how can I run the method getPathBetween ?

I tried this , but with no avail :

```
$ java MyClass.getPathBetween("some text", "some","text")
```

Comment: The short answer is that you can't. You must build such choice into the application itself

Comment: You might be interested in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop), [*JShell*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jshell/introduction-jshell.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//You can create an instance of MyClass in your main() method
// and then call getPathBetween():
public class MyClass{    
   public String getPathBetween(String path, String folderName, String extension){..}
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
      String path = "/some/path/value";
      String folder = "my-test-folder";
      String extension = "xyz";
      String pathBetween = myClassInstance.getPathBetween(path, folder, extension);
      System.out.println("pathBetween=" + pathBetween);
   }
}
```

Or if you want to be able to pass values into `getPathBetween()` from the command line, you could change the code to:

```
public class MyClass{    
   public String getPathBetween(String path, String folderName, String extension){..}
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
     MyClass myClassInstance = new MyClass();
     String path = args[0];
     String folder = args[1];
     String extension = args[2];
     String pathBetween = myClassInstance.getPathBetween(path, folder, extension);
     System.out.println("pathBetween=" + pathBetween);
  }
}
```

And then run it like so:

```
java MyClass "some text" "some" "text"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the method from `main`. The entry point of a program is always `main`.

Comment: Meaning that, if I want to execute a specific method I need to capture the instruction in the arg method and process it in the main ?

Comment: @vanessen - yup, that's right.

Comment: Or you ask for input in the program and use that to make the choice.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [Answer by ndc85430](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330630/642706), the method names `main` is always the entry point for a Java app executed in the command line (console).

## User can pass arguments

As noted in the [Answer by Mickey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72330694/642706), the user can pass arguments while calling your Java app on the command-line.

See [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) provided by Oracle.

## Interact with user via prompts & menus

You also have the ability to interact with the user on the command line. Use `System.out` to print instructions and menu options to be read by the user. Use a `Scanner` object to receive and parse input typed by the user on the command line.

See this tutorial by Oracle, [*I/O from the Command Line*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/cl.html).

Search Stack Overflow to find many examples. This approach is frequently used in tutorials and textbooks for beginning Java students.

## REPL

You might be interested in the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) bundled with Java, [*JShell*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jshell/introduction-jshell.html).

With JShell, you can type Java code to be executed immediately. You can instantiate an object if your class. And you can invoke methods on that object.